# Apache won't start in XAMPP

Tags: apache2, xampp

I'm trying to start XAMPP server via :

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Get me :

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

As you can see above, all packages run successfully except Apache.

Please tell me what to do ?

**Edit:**

The `netstat -a -no` output was a long file and i saved it on a [third-party site](http://www.beetxt.com/YgY/).

Comment: Output of `netstat -a -no`? add it to [Ubuntu Pasebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: First post edited. I've put the output http://www.beetxt.com/YgY/

Comment: Try `sudo ps -u apache`

Comment: The output is http://sharetext.org/V62I

Comment: Try this: stop all the servers and then try starting them again.

Comment: @Mitch You mean restart xampp via `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` ?

Comment: Yes, Stop, and Re-start.

Comment: Problem not solved :(

Comment: `sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`, Change “nobody” to your username, and restart.

Comment: There is no "nobody" text in that file.

Comment: So it does have your username? It also might be "nogroup"

Comment: I stored that file content here http://textsave.de/5FJ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10076/discussion-between-mitch-and-hamed-kamrava)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't start Xampp on ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340363/i-cant-start-xampp-on-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 21):

Try using this :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

then try starting your xampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sammy but what does the `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` stop?

Comment: also you can use this command 
```sudo apachectl stop && sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start```