# I can't start Xampp on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apache2, xampp

I have installed Xampp 1.8.3.1  .run file. and when I type

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

then  it gives me a message like this

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Comment: sudo: /etc/init.d/apache2: command not found
when i am hit the command show like this

Comment: Hi i faced the same issue and have tried mitch's solution to fix it, it works because i get this message on the terminal Starting Appache... Ok But while lampp started... I m not seeing how to use it. I m not seeing any lampp window on my computer

Comment: Skype is using/blocking port `80`, afaik

Comment: I solved the problem by opening /opt/lamp/xamp and edited the line `if testport 80` to `if testport 8080`. Now, test the thing by open the url `http://localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got a web server running on port 80. I see three viable choices:

1. Move XAMPP's version of Apache to a different port
2. Move whatever httpd is running on port 80 to another port (or remove it)
3. Just install `lamp-server^` (a real production stack) and stop messing around with XAMPP (which is really just a toy for Windows developers)

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: It works flawlessly!

Comment: command not found. ubuntu 13.10

Comment: How did you install Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, but these fixes didn't work for me. This post on the same forum solved my issues... I literally tried everything else :) Working great now though.

[[Cannot start XAMPP on Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89156/cannot-start-xampp-on-ubuntu-11-10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89156/cannot-start-xampp-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Thanks, hope this helps somebody.